# Ajax request duplicate on page call back

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, multiplication

I made an ajax script that call the page asked in a `#container` div in php, so if i call the project.html page, the request working well, calling the page and the `$getscript` associate but if i try to call back my home page the requests are duplicate:

[image]

There is my php function:

```html
 <?php $d="pages/" ; if(isset($_GET[ 'p'])){ $p=strtolower($_GET[ 'p']); if(preg_match( "/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/",$p) && file_exists($d.$p. ".html")){ include $d.$p. ".html"; } else{ include $d. "404.html"; } } else{ include $d. "home.html"; } ?>
```

and this is my ajax request:

```js
var afficher = function(data, page) {

    $('#container').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#container').empty();
        $('#container').append(data);
  
        $('#container').fadeIn(100, function() {});

    });
};

var loadPage = function(page, storeHistory) {
    if (typeof storeHistory === 'undefined') {
        storeHistory = true;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pages/' + page,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            afficher(html, page);
            if (storeHistory === true) {
                history.pushState({
                    'key': 'value',
                    'url': page
                }, '', page);
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            afficher('erreur lors du chagement de la page');
        }
    });

    return false;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
            if (e.state === null) {
                loadPage('home.html');
            } else {
                loadPage(e['state']['url'], false);
            }
        });
    }, 0);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.project a').on('click', function(e) {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        loadPage(page);
        return false;
    });

  $('#menu a').on('click', function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        loadPage(page);
        return false;
    });
  
 });
```

How can i fix the problem of multiple request when i call my home page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is somehow the event is getting added again and again. One temperary solution and suggested solution will be to abort the previous ajax everytime you call another ajax. So it can be:

```
var lastRequest = null;
if(lastRequest!=null){
lastRequest.abort();
}
lastRequest = $.ajax({
//your code
    });
```

So, by this way there will only one active ajax at a time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that working for the first ajax call back but the problem come back

Comment: is the problem coming even after abort ?

Comment: actually the problem is coming only when clicking the ' #menu a ', the onpopstate request is working well

Comment: I think I got the issue to multiple request, one  request is going when loadPage is called through onClick event is getting triggered and second request is going when window load event listner is called

Comment: Can you change the event statement to  $('#menu a').bind('click',function(){..... and also write this statement before that  $('#menu a').unbind();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116220/discussion-between-tiaw-and-aman-chhabra).